# If two cells match/duplicates, return and calculate value from second

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a database with various codes and costs allocated to each and looking for a formula to help calculate various costs if their codes match/duplicate.

If codes match/ duplicate in column A then their corresponding cost (column B, in the same row as code) returned in column C

The costs would need to add together, which is where I'm struggling

Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: pls provide example of how it should look like the result

Comment: A2 and A8 match so I'd like B2 and B8 to add up and placed in column C. Also A3 and A4, so B3 and B4 would add up and placed in column C.  Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest way would be to query it out:

```
=QUERY(A:B; "select A,sum(B) group by A"; 1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: That's amazing! you've actually done it! Thank you :D